# SSIS using web interface

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I am beginning to learn SSIS and I have built my first package, which loads data from excel into SQL Server (using stored procedures for some complex inserts). The package has variables and parameters. I am just wondering if it is possible to integrate a web form that users can use to enter values for these parameters without having to enter them from SSMS or SSIS. Anyone tried setting variables and parameters in a web form instead? Maybe a naive question but just starting to work with SSIS.

Comment: Maybe a script task and then code in c#?

Answer (score 2):

You can use ISCatalog for programmatically pass variables and execute the packages: Below is the sample code

```
PackageInfo myPackage = integrationServices.Catalogs[“SSISDB”].Folders[“MyFolder”].Projects[“MyProject”].Packages[“MyPackage.dtsx”];
PackageInfo.ExecutionValueParameterSet { ParameterName = “myStringParameter2”, ParameterValue = “myStringParameter2Value”, ObjectType = 30 });
myPackage.Execute(true, null, executionValueParameterSet);
```